# bootstrap carousel indicators custom class addition

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add custom class for bootstrap carousel since i want the changes to the carousel indicators to reflect only at one point of the application

This is my code

HTML:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators custom">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active "></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.custom .carousel-indicators .active {
    background:green !important;
}
.custom .carousel-indicators li {
    border:2px solid black !important;
}
```

But i am not able to see any of my changes in the carousel indicators.
Please provide me the correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `.custom` and `.carousel-indicators`.

The space signifies that `.carousel-indicators` is a *descendant* of `.custom` when in fact they are the same element.

```css
.custom.carousel-indicators .active {
  background: green !important;
}

.custom.carousel-indicators li {
  border: 2px solid black !important;
}
```

```html
<ol class="carousel-indicators custom">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active "></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
</ol>
```